# Have Stack Overflow Keyboard Glyphs on my blog

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put a Keyboard shortcut on my blog and was considering using a resource like the Stack Overflow keyboard glyphs, which are awesome:

<kbd>A</kbd>
<kbd>W</kbd>
<kbd>E</kbd>
<kbd>S</kbd>
<kbd>O</kbd>
<kbd>M</kbd>
<kbd>E</kbd>

Is there a easy way to do this without too many images? I don't have a lot of space on my blog.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I stole this from Stackoverflow CSS:

```
kbd{
    padding:2px 4px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    color:#000;
    background:#eee;
    border-width:1px 3px 3px 1px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#ccc #aaa #888 #bbb;
}
```

It should be what you're looking for. Just add it to your CSS. To use it, enclose the letter you want in `<kbd>` tags.